# Xslt Substring before or after space existing at some nth position

Tags: substring, contains

If length of String_1 is greater than 30 then I need to pull substring before or after Space that is nearest to length 30 of String_1 to the nearest space. And rest of the String_1 should be concatenated to String_2

Hello All,
Appreciate the solutions

I have two strings
String_1: 'I go by walk daily and sometimes I go by bus or bike'
with more with length range 20 t0 40,
String_2: 'No Train'
with more with length range 10,

If length of String_1 is greater than 30 then I need to pull substring before or after Space that is nearest to length 30 of String_1 to the nearest space. And rest of the String_1 should be concatenated to String_2